# Error in Hungerford's algebra proof? Left id & inv = group

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Prop 1.3 in Hungerford's Algebra said that if $G$ is a semigroup and there exist a left identity and each element have a left inverse, then $G$ is a group. The proof (and in fact, even the proposition themselves) implicitly assumed that the left identity is unique, but I can't quite see how it could be proved. Is this a mistake, or is there a way to prove that?

EDIT: for definiteness, this is the exact statement as given:

Proposition 1.3. Let $G$ be a semigroup. Then $G$ is a group if and only if the following conditions hold:

(i) There exist an element $e\in G$ such that $ea=a$ for all $a\in G$ (left identity element);

(ii) For each $a\in G$, there exists an element $a^{-1}\in G$ such that $a^{-1}a=e$ (left inverse).

EDIT: in light of the discussion on the range of quantifier, the answer below showed that it is provable as long as the quantifier in (i) range all the way to include (ii). I still wish to ask whether we can prove it even if the quantifier only range within (i), ie. (ii) should be interpreted as: for each $a\in G$, there exists an element $a^{-1}\in G$ such that $a^{-1}a=e$ where $e$ is one of those left identities.

Comment: What is an inverse if the identity is not unique?

Comment: @MarkBennet: that's why I said that the proposition itself seems to already imply uniqueness. However, it can make sense to define inverse in a way that make sense even without unique identity. $a^{-1}$ is a left inverse of $a$ if for all $b$ then $a^{-1}ab=b$.

Comment: @gina doesn't that imply then that as soon as the semigroup is non-empty and has left inverses, it also has left identities? (Though the left identities may not be unique.) Why mention left identities then if they're forced to exist by the inverses?

Comment: @DanielRust: perhaps just for reason of clarity. We could similarly omit the requirement that identity exist for group (and combine that with the requirement that inverse exist), but I never see any books doing that.

Comment: The proposition assumes there exists and element called $e$ which is a left identity and such that for this particular left identity, there are left inverses. There could also be some different left identity, but that's not the one used in (ii).

Comment: Mixedmath's proof then shows that this element is unique.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: I guess this could just be a case of ambiguous phrasing. (note that pretty much every book on group theory phrase the group axioms the same way, but in the case of group there are no ambiguities as we can prove that identity is unique)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I separate this answer, because it relies on an edit and a misreading of the original statement from Hungerford.

But let us suppose that there is at least one left identity called $e$, and each element $g$ has a "loose left inverse" $g^{-1}$ such that $g^{-1}g$ is a left identity, which may or may not be $e$.

Then we cannot conclude that $G$ is a group.

For instance, consider the two element semigroup with multiplication table

$$\begin{array}{l|ll}
G & e & g \\
\hline
e & e & g \\
g & e & g
\end{array}$$

In this case, every element is a left identity. For that matter, each element is a "loose left inverse" of both itself and the other element.

Comment: Ah I see, so it looks like the weaker hypothesis cannot work after all.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start by showing that left inverses are also right inverses. Take some element $g$ from the group, and denote a left identity by $e$. Then we know that

$$ g^{-1} = eg^{-1} = (g^{-1}g)g^{-1} = g^{-1}(gg^{-1}).$$

Then this means that

$$ e = (g^{-1})^{-1}g^{-1} = (g^{-1})^{-1}\left(g^{-1}(gg^{-1})\right) = \left((g^{-1})^{-1}g^{-1}\right)gg^{-1} = egg^{-1} = gg^{-1},$$

so that the left inverse is also a right inverse. Notice that we did not use right identity or right inverse so far. With this, showing that the left identity is also a right identity is very easy.

$$ g = eg = (gg^{-1})g = g(g^{-1}g) = ge,$$

and so both the left identity and left inverses are actually also a right identity and right inverses.

With this, you can carry out the standard proof that identities and inverses are unique. Suppose $e, e'$ are two identities. Then

$$e = ee' = e'.$$

Suppose $h, h'$ are both inverses to $g$. Then

$$ h = he = h(gh') = (hg)h' = eh' = h'.$$

So we get uniqueness and right-ness from having just a left identity and left inverse. $\diamondsuit$

Comment: You already assume uniqueness right from step one: "the identity".

Comment: Well how would you define 'left inverse' if there were more than one identity?

Comment: Actually, I'll answer myself. One way of encoding the idea of an inverse without explicitly referring to an identity element is stating that equations are solvable. For instance, you could say that for every a,b in G the equation xa = b has a solution in G--this replaces the 'left inverse' axiom.

Comment: @AlexZorn: Referring to Hungerford's exercise, he is saying that left inverses exist with respect to one left identity called $e$, even if there might be some other left identity.

Comment: Well in that case you can interpret 'the identity' in mixedmath's post as the one specified by the left inverses axiom.

Comment: @AlexZorn: indeed! This proof is fine.

Comment: @Gina: Indeed, I replaced "the identity" by "an identity", which I happen to call $e$. Everything then works fine.

Comment: I see, so that means that you interpreted the quantifier "there exist" from part (i) of the proposition range all the way until the end of (ii), which means that there are a left identity that also, with respect to it, every element have left inverse. In that case, the proof work. However, it remained to be answered whether it can still be proved even if there is no single such $e$ (ie. every element still have a left inverse, but that left inverse could be with respect to a different left identity)

Comment: @Gina: I didn't assume any more than you gave me. You wrote exactly that every element $a$ has an inverse $a^{-1}$ such that $a^{-1}a = e$. You named this element in the first part.

Comment: If it is not necessarily the case that $a^{-1}a=(a^{-1})^{-1}a^{-1}$ for any $a$ then this proof does not work. I interpreted (ii) as using $e$ as a short hand for just some left identity, not a fixed one indicated in (i), which means that there could be a different $e$ depending on $a$.